# Highlight and Bold text in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, bold

I am trying to add some code to myHighlighter class so that i can highlight and turn BOLD the part of the text i want.My first try was not successful..

```
Highlighter.HighlightPainter myHighlightPainter = 
              new MyHighlightPainter(Color.red,Font.BOLD); 

class MyHighlightPainter extends DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter { 

     public MyHighlightPainter(Color color, int Font) { 
         super(color);
     }
```

Also i am trying to avoid Graphics...

Comment: Other than using HTML as mentioned below, you can use a StyledDocument to change the text attributes, as suggested [in a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766396/how-do-i-easily-edit-the-style-of-the-selected-text-in-a-jtextpane)

Comment: I solved it this way. I add a method for Bold Font with the help of StyledDocument and put it to run in a Thread after the Highlight method.Thanks!

Comment: what was the question? Why did you show a code snippet that adds exactly nothing to super behaviour?

Comment: I was trying to add the bold action inside MyhighlightPainter class.

Comment: what exactly did you try? Your snippet doesn't do anything ...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the text to HTML? I believe the `JTextPane` supports HTML, so try setting your text to something like:

```
myTextPane.setText("<html>This text box has <b>bold text</b> in it!</html>");
```

Comment: I had to set the property `contentType` in JTextPane to `text/html` to make it work.