# How to display the name of the Action in the combo box

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I am trying already some days to get my code working but with no success jet.
I think that my code explain my problem. I don't know how to see in the combo box item for example "Serif".. I see the hash code of the action..The part of the code which is in comment are my unsuccessful attempt to make it work correctly.
I think here is the solution to my code but I can't get it work:
[action listener in another class - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985507/action-listener-in-another-class-java)

```
 public class ComboBoxFontFamilyAction extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    public ComboBoxFontFamilyAction() {
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem(new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("Red", Color.red));
        comboBox.addItem(new StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction("Serif"
                .toString(), "Serif"));

        // When I click on this item I get the error
        comboBox.addItem(new FontSetting(new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction(
                "Red", Color.red), "Read what you want", comboBox));

        comboBox.addItemListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(comboBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText("Some text to change attributes of.");
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textPane));

        // I think that i should do something like that
        // ItemListener itemListener = new FontSetting(new
        // StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("Red", Color.red),
        // "Wohoo",comboBox);
        // comboBox.addItemListener(itemListener);

    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Action action = (Action) e.getItem();
        action.actionPerformed(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComboBoxFontFamilyAction frame = new ComboBoxFontFamilyAction();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}


    //public class FontSetting implements ItemListener {

public class FontSetting {

    private StyledEditorKit.StyledTextAction textAction;
    private String displayValue;

    // private JComboBox comboBox1;

    public FontSetting(StyledEditorKit.StyledTextAction textAction,
            String displayValue, JComboBox comboBox1) {
        this.textAction = textAction;
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
        // this.comboBox1 = comboBox1;

    }

    // public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    // Action action = (Action) e.getItem();
    // action.actionPerformed(null);
    // }

    public String toString() {
        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

Thx in advance for any help :)

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JComboBox and Document (for JTextPane/EditorPane)

Comment: I think this is already a SSCCE of my problem.

Comment: can  [be based on](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9958004/714968), or why bothering, isn't it,  [Visual Font Designer by  Darryl Burke](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/30/visual-font-designer/)

Comment: Hm I took a look at both of yours links, I also tried Visual Font Designer. But as I tested it I can said that this is not what I am searching.. In both of the examples it changes the font (for example) for the whole text area..if you try my example you will see that when you change font (for example), the font will be different for the new letters-> it will not change the font formatting of the text before..

Comment: I would expect from your question at least two things more - hash code that you see, and code of FontFamilyAction

Answer (score 1):

You see hash code probably because you are not overriding `toString()` method of `StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction`.

You should override it to return reasonable string ("Serif"), or use `JComboBox.setRenderer(ListCellRenderer)` to set custom renderer that renders created `StyledEditorKit.FontFamilyAction` to reasonable text.

Comment: Thank you very much, at the end I decided to create a menubar and to put everything in the menubar. I fond it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766396/how-do-i-easily-edit-the-style-of-the-selected-text-in-a-jtextpane